# PDF Blob - Window.open not showing content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to display in frontend a pdf file that comes from the backend, but the new window only shows the PDF controls.
Could someone evaluate my code and indicate what I'm doing wrong?

Backend code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/capaRdv/{idRdv}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void relatorioCapaRdv(@PathVariable Integer idRdv, HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException, SQLException, IOException {
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("idRdv", idRdv);
        InputStream jasperStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/capaRdv.jasper");
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource.getConnection());
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=capaRdv" + idRdv + ".pdf");
        final OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outStream);
    }
```

Frontend code:

```
emiteRelatorio(idRdv) {
  const url = `${baseApiUrl}/relatorios/capaRdv/${idRdv}`;
  axios
    .post(url, { responseType: "blob" })
    .then(res => {
      const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      window.open(fileURL);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      Swal.fire({
        text: error.response.data.error,
        type: "error",
        confirmButtonClass: "md-button md-danger btn-fill",
        buttonsStyling: false
      });
    });
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SViNp.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Ndb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the POST method to GET:

`method = RequestMethod.GET`

`axios.get`